# How can I modify a specific class instance from the method of another class in a different module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, class-method

I wish to have a class method that directly acts on a specific instance of another class. I can achieve this if both classes are defined and instantiated in the same module, but it falls apart when I try to import the classes to a second module.

Here is a test code snippet that shows my problem:

```
# Module 1
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def increase_value(self):
        self.value += 1


class Bar:
    def read_foo(self):
        foo_value = foo.get_value()
        #Do something with Foo_value
        return foo_value
```

Then, in another module, an instance of each of these classes is created with a strict name that matches that of the class methods.

```
# Module 2
import test

foo = test.Foo()
bar = test.Bar()
print(bar.read_foo())
```

Now when module 2 is run, it returns a 'foo is not defined' error because foo was not created in module 1. How can I resolve this?

EDIT: My solution as mentioned in the first comment is to pass foo as an argument to the class method read_foo, like so:

```
class Bar:
    def read_foo(self, foo):
        foo_value = foo.get_value()
        #Do something with Foo_value
        return foo_value
```

Comment: Are these modules that you wrote yourself or are they PyPI modules? This seems to not work because Bar's read_foo() function is accessing a variable (foo) that isn't global or not defined within the function. If this is a module you wrote, you could try passing in an object of type Foo into Bar's read_foo() function

Comment: I've written these modules myself. Now I feel like an idiot because your solution was so simple! Thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

The weakref module might have what you're looking for - it lets you make references to an object that will point back to it.  Another option if that library functionality doesn't work perfectly for you is to just access the object by it's memory location (found by hex(id(object))).

Comment: The fact that an object's `id` is its address is an implementation detail, not a guarantee.  Manipulating Python objects by messing with their underlying memory is **_always_** a bad idea, and the question doesn't need weakrefs, so neither of your suggestions is a good idea.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the clarification. Looks like I need to school me some more.  Is there a "good" way for pointer-esque manipulation of objects like there is in C, or is that just not really pythonic to interact with objects that way?

Comment: If you have a reference to an object, you can mess with it as you like. Object protection in Python is only by convention; the language assumes we're all consenting adults.  Messing around with the C-level structures is right out (i.e. not at all Pythonic).